# Regex: Exact match string ending with specific character

Tags: regex

I'm using Java. So I have a comma separated list of strings in this form:

```
aa,aab,aac
aab,aa,aac
aab,aac,aa
```

I want to use regex to remove aa and the trailing ',' if it is not the last string in the list. I need to end up with the following result in all 3 cases:

```
aab,aac
```

Currently I am using the following pattern:

```
"aa[,]?"
```

However it is returning:

```
b,c
```

Comment: What flavor regex are you using? Does it know `\b`?

Comment: if it is not the last string in the list then just match `aa,`

Comment: Is it .NET? JavaScript?

Comment: This will be used in Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If lookarounds are available, you can write:

```
,aa(?![^,])|(?<![^,])aa,
```

with an empty string as replacement.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/Su6AtE/1)

Otherwise, with a POSIX ERE syntax you can do it with a capture:

```
^(aa(,|$))+|(,aa)+(,|$)
```

with the 4th group as replacement (so $4 or \4)

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/KsQWDR/1)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your flavor, I propose this solution for the case that it does know the `\b`.

I use perl as demo environment and do a replace with "_" for demonstration.

```
perl -pe "s/\baa,|,aa\b/_/"
```

`\b` is the "word border" anchor. I.e. any start or end of something looking like a word. It allows to handle line end, line start, blank, comma.
Using it, two alternatives suffice to cover all the cases in your sample input.

Output (with interleaved input, with both, line ending in newline and line ending in blank):

```
aa,aab,aac
_aab,aac
aab,aa,aac
aab_,aac
aab,aac,aa
aab,aac_
aa,aab,aac 
_aab,aac
aab,aa,aac 
aab_,aac
aab,aac,aa 
aab,aac_
```

If the `\b` is unknown in your regex engine, then please state which one you are using, i.e. which tool (e.g. perl, awk, notepad++, sed, ...). Also in that case it might be necessary to do replacing instead of deleting, i.e. to fine tune a "," or "" as replacement. For supporting that, please show the context of your regex, i.e. the replacing mechanism you are using. If you are deleting, then please switch to replacing beforehand.

*(I picked up an input from comment by gisek, that the cpaturing groups are not needed. I usually use `()` generously, including in other syntaxes. In my opinion not having to think or look up evaluation orders is a benefit in total time and risks taken. But after testing, I use this terser/eleganter way.)*

Comment: Nice solution. The groups are unnecessary though :)

Comment: @gisek Thanks. I am aware that my approach to use `()` generously (including in other syntaxes)sometimes leads to a little unnecessary code. On the other hand inexperienced or potentially distracted programmers (like me), have it easier to see/understand what is happening, without looking up operator precedences and similar. As long as they do not get in the way (which admittedly is more probable here than e.g. in C expressions), I consider it a benefit in total time spent and risks taken. But your point is valid.

Comment: It was just a sidenote. I like that approach too.

Comment: @gisek Too late. :-) After testing it **is** the leaner way. I keep my reasoning however. Nice exchange, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to delete `aa` followed by a coma or the end of the line, this should do the trick: `,aa(?=,|$)|^aa,`

[see online demo](https://regex101.com/r/oD3mLQ/2)

Comment: If you add blanks at the end of the input lines your solution does not work for "aab,aac,aa ". It is a little speculative, but the sample input by OP seems to imply the possibility of lines ending in newline or blank and newline. Your updated proposal does however work for the sample input as given. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

If your regex engine supports `positive lookaheads` and `positive lookbehinds`, this should work:

```
,aa(?=,)|(?<=,)aa,|(,|^)aa(,|$)
```

Comment: Not sure, but it seems that OPs input can end in blank or newline (admittedly speculating). In case of blank, the "aaab,aac,aa " does not seem to work as OP wants with your expression.

Comment: @Yunnosch If so, the fix is trivial: `,aa(?=,)|(,|^)aa(,|$| )+` or even `,aa(?=,)|(,|^)aa(,|$|\s)+`

Comment: It doesn't work for the string `aa,aa,ab` because the first comma is consumed by the first match (the second branch succeeds). You can solve the problem (and reduce the whole pattern to a unique branch) writing: `(,|^)aa(?![^,])` (or `(?<![^,])aa(?![^,])` if lookbehind are supported)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Good point. I fixed my regex. Your approach fails on this example `aa,aa,ab,aa,aa`. Still I think Yunnosch's solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the following and replace it by nothing :

```
(aa,|,aa$)
```

1. Either `aa,` when it's in the begin or the middle of a string
2. `,aa$` when it's at the end of the string

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/LuG264/1)